# Cron don´t run python files that imports modules

Tags: 14.04, python, cron

I´ve been struggling for a long time with cron running .py files and it seems to be caused when importing modules and py files from same dir. Log files return content correctly when no module or is imported. py files from same dir works though. Same thing if I run it as non-superuser or root. Files are written in python 3. It must have something to do with my PATH settings. Ubuntu 14.04

my crontab settings:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/tester.py > /home/user/log.txt
```

Comment: Is it really "your crontab" - or root's? If you're certain that it is something to do with your `PATH`, then have you tried setting an identical `PATH` in your crontab?

Comment: It is and set PATH as well. In another project has no problem importing smtp module. I wonder if it´s the placement of phantomjs, selenium that my files are trying to import. Also tried to add shebangs to my py files.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the MAILTO tag in crontab I checked the error message. The problem was the driver path (in this case Chromedriver) wthat had to be an absolute path to Chromedrivers location.